# no aparece form al querer llamar desde clase en visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Resulta que tengo una clase donde hago todas mis consultas ql, puntualmente en una que hago un update, quiero llamar al form para indicar el textbox donde esta un dato que voy a editar, pero el form no aparece ese en particulas, si aparecen otros.

Esta es la clase, y el form se llama CreaUbicacion:
(al empezar a escribir el nombre del form (CreaUbicacion), deberia salir en la lista desplegable, y no aparece, pero si salen los otros form)

```
Public Sub editacreaubicacion()
    Dim insertar As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    insertar.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    insertar.CommandText = "UPDATE creaubicacion SET tipo = '" & creaubicacion.textbox1.Text & "' WHERE idcomplementaria = '" & creaubicacion.tbxIdComple.Text & "'"
    insertar.Connection = conectar
    Try
        If ((insertar.ExecuteNonQuery() <> 0)) Then

            MessageBox.Show("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO")

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sera que no tiene ninguna propiedad publica y por eso no aparece? igual, no deberias llamar al form. El metodo deberia recibir los parametros que necesita.

Comment: es public class el form

Comment: Esta en otro namespace? necesitas importarlo? pueden ser multiples los motivos...

Comment: esta exactamente igual que los otros form de mi proyecto, y es el unico que no puedo "llamar"

Comment: limpia tu solucion. vuelve a compilar tu proyecto.

Comment: nada :( no es primera vez que me pasa y la unica solucion era volver a crear el form y copiar el codigo... no queria hacer lo mismo de nuevo

Comment: La forma mas rapida de la que lo soluciono es cambiando el nombre al form por uno distinto, y ahi aparece,,